# Cannot load protocol buffer with ReadBinaryProto Tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am having issues loading my protocol buffer file saved from a tensorflow model in C++. I can load and execute the .pb file in Python with no issues at all, however when trying to load it in C++ with the `ReadBinaryProto` function I get the error:

```
String field'tensorflow.MetaGraphDef.MetaInfoDef.tensorflow_version' 
   contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' 
   type if you intend to send raw bytes.

   Non-OK-status: LoadModel(session_inception, pathToGraph ) status: Data loss: 
   Can't parse E:/Projects/SampleTensorflow/tmp/latestmodel.pb as binary proto
```

I am using **Tensorflow v1.10** and a sample of the C++ code is posted below, I have tried many different methods to save the .pb file including using the freeze_graph method and the `tf.write_graph` method, neither seem to fix the issue.

```
  tensorflow::Status LoadModel(tensorflow::Session *sess, std::string 
  graph_fn, std::string checkpoint_fn = "") {
  tensorflow::Status status;

  std::string graph_fn = "E:/Projects/SampleTensorflow/tmp/latestmodel.pb";      

  // Read in the protobuf graph
  tensorflow::MetaGraphDef graph_def;
  status = ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_fn, 
                            &graph_def);

  if (status != tensorflow::Status::OK())
    return status;

  // Create the graph
  status = sess->Create(graph_def.graph_def());
  if (status != tensorflow::Status::OK())
      return status;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: caveat: Are you using the same protobuf version like TF does?

Comment: The protobuf files come with the install of TF, so I assume I do unless I have to install them separately somehow?

Comment: Are you sure the pb contains a `MetaGraphDef` and not a `GraphDef`? How do you read it in python?

Comment: @P-Gn Doh! I am fairly sure the graph was exported as a GraphDef not a MetaGraphDef. I will now try to update the C++ code to accommodate this or is there an easier way to export a MetaGraphDef?

Comment: I think the preferred way of using `MetaGraphDef`s is actually via [`SavedModelBundle`s](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/SavedModelBundle). It is fairly easy to use but would require more change to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible error is that the `.pb` file contains a `GraphDef` and not a `MetaGraphDef`.

To read a `GraphDef`, simply switch to

```
tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
status = ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_fn, 
                        &graph_def);
```

The protobuf format is indeed just a container, which says nothing about what it contains. In tensorflow, this format is commonly used both to contain graphs and metagraphs, which can be confusing.

Comment: Just something to add, I have noticed that the .pb file now initialises, but seems to give no proper output predictions with 'uninitialized tensor of 3 elements'. Is this due to the fact that the Meta data is needed in order to use it correctly, although in python I seem to be able to make accurate predictions with just the .pb file alone. Thanks again

Comment: If your graph still contains variables, then `SavedModelBundle`s are a good way to pack everything. Simple graphs can still be useful when you freeze your graph, converting all variables into constants. Metadata is by no means needed in those cases.

Comment: Had the same issue for a few days and finally fixed it thanks to this answer. Really appreciate it!